# jQuery prop() method works, but it doesn't add the "disabled" attribute to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable a button for prevent adding new rows in table.
My problem is that `prop()` method work fine, but doesn't disable button (I can't add new rows, its worked fine, but button still click and looks like "active" (and attribute "disabled" not added to my button)).

If I use `attr("disabled", "disabled")` instead of `prop("disabled", true)` that works fine and button disabling (attribute "disabled" added to element), but I read what to use `attr()` is bad after JQuery 1.6+.

```
var addBtn = $(".k-grid-add");
addBtn.bind("click", function () {
    if (grid.dataSource.data().length == 9) {
        $(addBtn).prop("disabled", true);          // <- work, but button still "active"
        // $(addBtn).attr("disabled", "disabled"); // <- work fine
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try to $(this).prop("disabled", true); in on click function.

Comment: not `$(addBtn).prop("disabled", true);` but `addBtn.prop("disabled", true)`

Answer (score 0):

Since `disabled` is a Boolean attribute, you need to set it like `disabled="disabled"`:

```
$(addBtn).prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: example from spec (http://api.jquery.com/prop/):
    $( "input" ).prop( "disabled", false );

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me ! Just look what I tested ....

```js
addBtn = $("#btn");
addBtn.prop("disabled", true);

addBtn.on("click",function() { console.log(999); });

//
enable.onclick = function() {
 addBtn.prop("disabled", false);
}

// 
disable.onclick = function() {
  addBtn.prop("disabled", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">sdf</button>

<button id="enable">Enable</button>
<button id="disable">Disable</button>
```

Comment: Button is disabed and cant click ! Isn't right ! @JackBashford

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify that, it should work. Here's a part my code, which is working, if I enter more than 6 characters, the buttons are active, if I delete it the buttons get disabled. What version of jQuery do you use? Also, the use of bind is deprecated in jQuery version >3.0, using `element.on()` will be more future proof (http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

```
$commentsInput.on('input.UECommenting', function (event) {
    let buttonsDisabled = $commentsInput.val().length < 7 ? true : false;
    for (let button in $commentingButtons) {
        $commentingButtons[button].prop({ 'disabled': buttonsDisabled, 'title': buttonsDisabled ? 'No comments without content!' : '' });
    }
});
```

And I have to recommend getting used to use namespaces for events, with that you can easily use `element.off('.namespace')` to ensure that your events wont be setted and fired multiple times.